# How do I host my laravel Project on google firebase

Tags: mysql, laravel, firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting

I'm working on a project where I used Vue.js as front end and laravel as backend and mysql as database. Now I want to deploy my whole project on google firebase. I did it for Vue.js portion but the functionality that are related to laravel is not working as I didn't deployed my laravel portion. How to interconnect both portion with each other on firebase hosing? Is it necessary to deploy my database also?

Comment: https://appdividend.com/2018/04/18/laravel-firebase-tutorial/?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, but firebase is a whole other beast different from SQL databases in general.

You would have to implement services to gather data from firebase with php itself, and probably wouldnt have much use for eloquent (the ORM that comes with Laravel).

So yes, you can but before doing that study what goal are you trying to obtain and if you should go the SQL or the NoSQL way.